# How to read a simple playlist in java

Tags: java, validation, input, http-live-streaming, urlconnection

I am trying to create a simple java command line code that will accept the URL from a playlist in command line and it should return the playlist content.

I am getting the following response back Enter playlist url here (0 to quit):
http://gv8748.lu.edu:8084/sweng987/simple-01/playlist.m3u8
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: http://lu8748.lu.edu:8084/sweng987/simple-01/playlist.m3u8

```
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:523)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:470)
at edu.lu.sweng987.SimplePlaylist.getPlaylistUrl(SimplePlaylist.java:36)
at edu.lu.sweng987.SimplePlaylist.main(SimplePlaylist.java:21)
```

My code is the following

```html
package edu.psgv.sweng861;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.*;

public class SimplePlaylist {

 private SimplePlaylist() {
  //don't allow instances
 }
 // The main function returns the URL entered 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 
  String output = getPlaylistUrl("");
  System.out.println(output);
  
  
 }
 

 private static String getPlaylistUrl(String theUrl) {
  String content = "";
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean validInput = false; 

  System.out.println("Enter playlist url here (0 to quit):");
   content = scanner.nextLine();
  try {
   URL url = new URL(theUrl);
   URLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
   String line;
   
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    content += line + "\n";
   }
   bufferedReader.close();
  } catch(Exception e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }  
  return content;
 }

 
 
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with your url rather than your code, have you tried pasting the url into a browser to see if it works

Comment: Yes the url works you just need to be under VPN to use it. code will work if I paste the url inside of the code and take out the scanner and input line but it does not return the playlist when I enter the url in the console input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrectly used the parameter for the method when creating the URL instance instead of the local variable actually containing the url

Change

```
content = scanner.nextLine();
try {
   URL url = new URL(theUrl);
```

to

```
content = scanner.nextLine();
try {
   URL url = new URL(content);
```

Comment: Please, learn to use the debugger. It's an excellent tool for pin-pointing this kind of mistakes.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to check if the url is a valid url or not ?

Comment: Surround just the URL url = new URL(content) with a try/catch and catch the MalformedURLException